# How do I read in a consecutive row of a text file in each step of a do-loop in fortran?

Tags: fortran, readfile, do-loops

I have a dataset of parameter values for 30 species, and I want to run a script that conducts a simulation for each species. The parameter values are currently stored in a .txt file, where each row is a different species, and each column is a different parameter value. What I'd like to do is set up a do-loop that reads in the relevant row of parameter values for each species, runs the simulation script, and writes a .txt file of the output for each species. Unfortunately, I'm new to fortran and having a lot of trouble understanding how to read in consecutive rows from a .txt file in each step of a do loop. I tried making a simplified script to test whether the read step was working:

```
    PROGRAM DRIVER
    IMPLICIT NONE

    INTEGER :: mm ! I forgot this line in the first version of this question   
    and edited to add it in
    CHARACTER(7) :: species  !! the first column is the species name
    REAL*8    :: leaf_variable   !  The next 3 columns are variable values
    REAL*8    :: stem_variable   !  
    REAL*8    :: root_variable   !  

    OPEN (12, file = "species_parameters.txt") ! open the .txt file

    DO mm = 1,30 ! set up the do loop
        READ (12,*) species, leaf_variable, stem_variable, root_variable
        ! Read in the species-specific parameter values
        WRITE (*,*) species, leaf_variable, stem_variable, root_variable
        ! Print the values on the screen just to show the do loop runs
    ENDDO
    END PROGRAM DRIVER
```

But when I go to compile, I get the error:
At line XX of file XX (unit = 12, file = 'species_parameters.txt')
Fortran runtime error: End of file

What am I misunderstanding about opening and reading in this file?

Thanks very much for any help.

EDIT: I think I've narrowed down my problem. My understanding is that read() takes in one row in a .txt file at a time, so that in this example:

```
    read(7, *) species, leaf_variable, stem_variable, root_variable
    read(7, *) species, leaf_variable, stem_variable, root_variable
```

The variables should equal the values in the second row of the .txt file. Instead, no matter how many times I put in the read() function, the variable values equal the first row. And, even though there are only 4 columns, I can define as many variables as I want with a read() function:

```
   read(7, *) species, leaf_variable, stem_variable, root_variable, 
            fake_variable1, fake_variable2, fake_variable3, fake_variable4
```

where the fake_variable values equal the values in the second row of the .txt file. Am I confused about what read() does, or is there something I need to do to keep my script from reading my entire .txt file as one line?

EDIT #2: The do loop reads line by line correctly now that I've saved my .txt file with Unix encoding using TextWrangler. The original file was saved as a .txt file with Excel. This seems to have solved it, but if anyone has suggestions for a better way to specify the input file format, I'd appreciate it. The first few lines of the input file look like this:

```
    species1,1.2,6.54,10.9
    species2,1.42,3.5,8.23
    species3,0.85,2.41,4.9
```

Comment: I don't see a type declaration for mm - the index variable of the do loop.  Consider showing a few lines from the input file.  Assuming that the lack of a type declaration is a transcription issue - a common issue is that the open statement is opening a new, empty file in a different directory to where the file actually is.  Make sure that you haven't created a file called `species_parameters.txt` somewhere else unexpected, add a STATUS='OLD' specifier to your open statement (which requires the file to be pre-existing), and try again.

Comment: I don't understand - you say you are getting a runtime error when you compile? On code which shouldn't actually compile.

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake-  the variable declaration for mm is the first line of my script and I somehow left it out. I edited my question to add that in. So my code does compile, and I still get the same runtime error when I tried STATUS = 'OLD'.

Comment: Your understanding about the behaviour of a read statement is inaccurate.  List directed read - where you have a `*` for the second specifier that specifies the format specification, as you do - reads as many complete records from the file as necessary to be able to process all the items in the input list.  If your input (**which we still haven't seen** - hence everybody is guessing!) only has data for four items in a record and you have eight items in the input list in the statement, then the read will read two records.  Show your actual code and your actual input!!!!

Comment: Thanks for your help, @IanH. I got the script to work by using TextWrangler to save the .txt input file, which I had originally saved in Excel, with Unix encoding. Is there a format specific I should use instead of *? I edited the question to include an example of my input file.

Comment: Are you using a Fortran compiler that [thinks it] is running on a unix system?  If so, then you need to provide it with text files that use the line ending convention that the compiler expects.  That isn't a Fortran language issue.

Answer (score 2):

A run time error is when you have an executable, execute it, and it crashes. A compile time error is when the compiler fails to produce an executable.

This code shouldn't compile, because you have `IMPLICIT NONE`, but haven't declared the integer `mm`.

What I'd recommend is to get more information:

```
program driver
    use iso_fortran_env
    implicit none
    character(len=7) :: species
    real(kind=real64) :: leaf_variable, stem_variable, root_variable
    integer :: u, ioerr
    character(len=120) :: iomsg

    open(newunit=u, file='species_parameters.txt', action='read', status='old', iostat=ioerr, iomsg=iomsg)
    if (ioerr /= 0) then
        print *, "Error opening file"
        print *, trim(iomsg)
        stop 1
    end if
    do
        read(u, *, iostat=ioerr, iomsg=iomsg) species, leaf_variable, stem_variable, root_variable
        if (ioerr /= 0) exit  ! exits the loop
        write(*, *) species, leaf_variable, stem_variable, root_variable
    end do
    print *, trim(iomsg)
    close(u)
end program driver
```

*This will always print the "read past end of file" error, but this is just to check how to program reads anyway.*

This should compile, and when you run it, it should give you some information on what is going wrong.

Comment: For test programs like this, the best way to get more information is to simply leave out the iostat from things like the input/output statements.  If an error condition occurs the Fortran processor will generally provide quite an informative message as part of error termination.  Look at the logic around the read statement in your example - if an error condition occurs during the read all your program does is quietly exit, and the user won't have a clue that something went wrong.  If you are going to supply IOSTAT then also supply (and report when iostat > 0) IOMSG.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I forgot to include the line of code that declared mm in my question, so I edited it to add that. Your code compiled, and printed the first row of variable values, without returning an error condition. But when I tried to run it over all the rows (with do mm =1,22), nothing printed, and it wrote an empty file called fort.1....  do you know what that means?

Comment: Sorry, that should be (do mm = 1, 30)

Comment: I noticed that I wrote `fortran_iso_env` instead of the proper `iso_fortran_env`. I also included the error messages as @IanH suggested.